# How to Insert Multiple rows with same field name Request.Form

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I have a form which gets the field values from database, all fields have their name and the record is looped from the database. *see below code*

```
<%
While Not RStmtbl.EOF
%>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="<% Response.Write(Rstmtbl("tdate"))%>" name="tdate_insert" readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<% Response.Write(Rstmtbl("day"))%>" name="day_insert" readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<% Response.Write(Rstmtbl("class"))%>" name="class_insert" readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<% Response.Write(Rstmtbl("pno"))%>" name="pno_insert" readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<% Response.Write(Rstmtbl("subject"))%>" name="subject_insert" readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<% Response.Write(Rstmtbl("teacher"))%>" name="teacher_insert" readonly /></td>
<td>
<select name="status_insert">
<option selected>Choose Status</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" value="<% Response.Write(formno) %>" name="uid_insert">
<input type="hidden" value="<% Response.Write(Now) %>" name="sdate_insert">
</td>
</tr>
<%
RStmtbl.Movenext
Wend
%>
```

Everything is fine at this point, HTML outputs all the records from access database,
But The problem occurs when i insert this form.

**Here is the Insert Code**

```
<%
if request.Form("TcfRecord")="Insert" then
Set InsCom=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
InsCom.ActiveConnection=objConn

InsTD = Trim(request.Form("tdate_insert"))
InsTD = replace(InsTD,"'","''")

InsTD2 = Trim(request.Form("day_insert"))
InsTD2 = replace(InsTD2,"'","''")

InsCL = Trim(request.Form("class_insert"))
InsCL = replace(InsCL,"'","''")

InsPI = Trim(request.Form("pno_insert"))
InsPI = replace(InsPI,"'","''")

InsSBI = Trim(request.Form("subject_insert"))
InsSBI = replace(InsSBI,"'","''")

InsTI = Trim(request.Form("teacher_insert"))
InsTI = replace(InsTI,"'","''")

InsSI = Trim(request.Form("status_insert"))
InsSI = replace(InsSI,"'","''")

InsUI = Trim(request.Form("uid_insert"))
InsUI = replace(InsUI,"'","''")

InsDI = Trim(request.Form("sdate_insert"))
InsDI = replace(InsDI,"'","''")

InsCom.CommandText = "Insert into time_table_status(tdate, day, class, pno, subject, teacher, status, uid, submit_date)Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@tdate_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsTD)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@day_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsTD2)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@class_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsCL)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@pno_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsPI)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@subject_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsSBI)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@teacher_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsTI)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@status_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsSI)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@uid_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsUI)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@sdate_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsDI)

InsCom.Execute

end if
%>
```

But it returns an error.

> Microsoft JET Database Engine (0x80040E14) Syntax error in INSERT INTO
>   statement.

I want to insert multiple rows with the same input field names, upon searching i found this solution. but it didn't work either...

```
<%
For Each item in Request.Form

' Above Insert Code

Next
%>
```

Please tell me whats wrong with the INSERT Statement. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Day` and `class` are both [reserved words](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html).  Enclose them in square brackets.

```
InsCom.CommandText = "Insert into time_table_status(tdate, [day], [class], pno, subject, teacher, status, uid, submit_date)Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```

Comment: oh, silly me. Why didn't i thought of that. thanks for pointing it out. but here another error came up `Microsoft JET Database Engine (0x80040E07) Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`

Comment: Would that be causing because im inserting multiple records with same name fields?

Comment: You have text as the data type for all the parameters, but are the destination fields all text data type?  For example, is `submit_date` actually a text field in the table?

Comment: yes, `tdate` data type was Time/Date. updated it.. Now record inserted successfully but there's another issue came up. The data is being inserted 6 times in each row and each cell :( i only want to insert 1 record per line.

Comment: Here is the [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68407113/img/tmbl.png)

Comment: Sorry but my ASP is rusty and I don't understand why that is happening.  My Access is solid enough to get you past the syntax error in the INSERT statement, but I'm lost now.  :-(

Comment: Thanks for helping me with INSERT Statement :) May be someone else can answer it